# Configuration for NGINX PHP Soap

Tags: php, nginx, soap, wsdl, yii-extensions

Here is my service call for NGINX and PHP with Yiiframework.

https://www.example.com/api/service?ws=1

I have added location config in nginx config as follow

```
location /api {
        rewrite ^/api/service /CWsdlGenerator.php?type=rest last;
      }
```

But I always got the following error _:

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://www.example.com/api/service' : failed to load external entity "https://www.example.com/api/service"

May I know what could be the issue?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I missed to install php-xml. After that I can see the WSDL XML.